# Android application doesn't show properly in mobizen and sidesync.

Tags: android

I created a mobile application using android 4.4.2.
I tried to share it using mobizen, and sidesync, in pc, some of the application activity on mobizen doesn't show (black color) but some can see. I tried using sidesync and it's also showing black color. I'm not sure what is wrong with my application. Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

Would love to know if you got this fixed so that I can pass this information along to our App team as a bug fix. I am trying to show our app and upon launch it shows the black screen. It used to work before one of the Mobizen updates.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Comment: Hi, in the end I used a monitor or tv to show (it works fine)...I'm still not sure what is the problem.